# How to make sure to not miss event

Tags: multithreading, events

Say I have a program that does the following:

- wait for key press
- Once key pressed, do complex query (takes 10 seconds) and print the result
- repeat

Now if I my key presses are 10 seconds apart, this would not be a problem. How do I handle key presses really close together. Even worse, keys pressed at the exact same time.
Is this information bound to be lost?
I know threading might be an option but what is general way of doing this?
Is it possible to just store every key pressed even though other code is running and be able to tend to it later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrupts.  Universally, computers provide a mechanism for peripherals to request the attention of a CPU by asserting an Interrupt Request Signal.   The CPU, when it is ready to accept interrupts, responds by saving minimal state somewhere, then executing code which can query the peripheral, possibly accepting data (keypress) from it.

If you are using an OS this is all hidden by the kernel, which typically exposes some mechanisms for you to choose how you want to deal with it:

1. Queue up the keypresses and process them later.  Thus if I want to have query 1,3,5 in that order, I can press those keys in succession and go for a smoke while your long processing occurs.
2. Discard the lookahead keypresses; thus demand the user interact with a lousy UI.  Search for "homer simpson work from home" to see how to work around this.

If you are using an OS, you might need to look up various ioctl's to enable this behaviour, use a UI packages similar to curses, or other.

If you aren't using an OS, your job is both tougher and easier: you have to write the code to talk to the keyboard, but implementing the policy is 1/10 th work of figuring out some baroque UI library.